# System.getProperty("user.home") returns null

Tags: java, android, environment-variables, filenotfoundexception

I was trying to access a file with a java scanner class but always got FileNotFoundException so i tried to output what my current working directory was `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));`
and it returned `null`

Do i have to manually set it somewhere in project settings or are my enviromental paths messed up? How can i fix this?

Comment: Try System.getProperty("user.home")

Comment: First, as deFreitas noted, it's `user.home` and not `user-home`. Second: you've tagged this [tag:android-studio] (which probably should have been just [tag:android]), so you should know that `user.home` doesn't have a real meaning on Android, there's no direct equivalent to "the user home directory" on Android. See [the relevant doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#getProperties()): it says "not useful on Android".

Comment: I meant "user.home", just a typo, sorry. So in that case how do i know where scanner expects me to put the targeted file? Because no matter if i use relative or absolute path i am still getting file not found error.

Comment: What are you trying to read? A file that's part of your project? Then you should load it as a resource and not try to treat it like a file. Are you trying to read a file that's user-provided? Then you'll need to request the appropriate permissions. File I/O on Android is [different than in "normal Java"](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).

Answer (score 1):

When you are on Android the traditional 'user.home' property has no specific meaning or equivalent to what it would in a traditional desktop java application.  However when running inside an Android runtime you should have access to the '[Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getDataDirectory())' class which defines a number of paths to relevant directories.

Take a look at the [getDataDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getDataDirectory()) call, which should give you a file object to the correct system path.